# Match CSV row to input then read from another column

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a complete novice, but I'm certain there must be a relatively simple solution for what I'm intending.

I'm just trying to match the first column in the CSV with the userinput, then when it finds a match it retrieves the next two values in the next two columns and assigns them to name and mark.

The user searches for the ID, the function sifts through the first index of every row, if it finds a match then it takes the next two columns in that row and puts it in 'name' and 'mark'.

The CSV file has entries on each new row formatted like this: 1,Bertrand,83
I've included the save function in case I've formatted it wrong.

I get the error IndexError: list index out of range
I've searched for hours and have tried to implement 3 solutions and nothing seems to work.

```
import csv

class studentProfile:

    def __init__(self, sid, name, mark):
        self.sid = sid
        self.name = name
        self.mark = mark


    def saveCsv(self):
        with open("studentDB.csv", "a") as csvfile:
            prowriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",", quotechar="|")
            prowriter.writerow([self.sid, self.name, self.mark])
            print("Profile {}({}) saved.".format(self.name, self.sid))


    def loadCsv(self):
        search = input("Enter a Student ID to retrieve profile: ")

        with open("studentDB.csv", "r") as csvfile:
            csvloader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",", quotechar="|")

            for row in csvloader:
                if search == row[0]:
                    self.sid = search
                    self.name = row[1]
                    self.mark = row[2]
```

EDIT: Used to have:

`search = list(input("Enter a Student ID to retrieve profile: "))`

Now corrected but the error persists:

Enter a Student ID to retrieve profile: 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\techn\Desktop\python workspace\zzzmypro\garbagebench.py", line 83, in 
    p1.loadCsv()
  File "C:\Users\techn\Desktop\python workspace\zzzmypro\garbagebench.py", line 48, in loadCsv
    if search == row[0]:
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: A csv file is a text file. What does the current `studentDV.csv` file contains? Could it have an empty first line?

Comment: I've solved it. I'm on a Windows computer, I think that's why this was required: with open("studentDB.csv", "a", newline="") as csvfile. I needed the newline part, now everything functions as normal - I think other systems don't need that to be designated. The problem was as you said, empty lines in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why did you put `list` to get the `search` tho?

You should change to `search = input("Enter a Student ID to retrieve profile: ")` and it works like a charm then. Here is your code with a little change to debug

[image]

Comment: My mistake, I actually did have that before but as I was trying new things I had left that in. It still doesn't work for me, I get IndexError: list index out of range at if search == [0]

Comment: I've now edited the main post to update the problem.

Comment: So there is some row that you dont have 3 values to unpack. try print out each row and see why then

Comment: Ok, so it seems that the file had spaces on a new line, so actually the save function doesn't work properly - it keeps adding spaces which creates an error - but why?

Comment: Try save some new `student` then, it works fine for me :/

Comment: I've solved it. I'm on a Windows computer, I think that's why this was required: with open("studentDB.csv", "a", newline="") as csvfile. I needed the newline part, now everything functions as normal - I think other systems don't need that to be designated.